# React native reanimated , application crashs when call setState in callback with withTiming or withSpring

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

My React Native `expo` application crashing without any error when call `function()` in `withTiming()` callback

**Example :**

```js
         
    const whenFinishFunction = () => {
        // do some thing
      };

    const [animationState, setAnimationState] = useState(false);
    
    progress.value = withTiming(1,{duration: 200},
          () => {
           whenFinishFunction();
           setAnimationState(false);
          }
        );
```

**Solved by use [runOnJS](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/miscellaneous/runOnJS/)**

like :

```js
    progress.value = withTiming(1,{duration: 200},
          () => {
            runOnJS(whenFinishFunction)();
            runOnJS(setAnimationState)(false);
          }
        );
```

Comment: It's worth nothing, for anybody coming across this, that `withTiming` and `runOnJS` are *very* picky about how you use them. It has to be an arrow function *literal* for the withTiming callback, and the *only* thing inside the literal has to be `runOnJS` called with a single locally defined function *reference*, and any passed arguments (as shown in the example).